# Replace outer HTML in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to write an AngularJS directive such as

```
<my-directive>
    <inner-body>
        normal HTML and Angular constructs
    </inner-body>
</my-directive>
```

And should be converted as

```
<div class="group">
  <div> directive inserted text </div>
  <div class="groupBody">
      normal HTML and Angular constructs
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want to have flexibility to write HTML inside `inner-body`. The directive will convert it to `div` and apply some attributes to this div.

Is it possible?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, use `ngTransclude` ([ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude))

Extract from AngularJS:

```
<script>
  angular.module('transcludeExample', [])
   .directive('pane', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { title:'@' },
        template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                    '<div style="background-color: gray">{{title}}</div>' +
                    '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
                  '</div>'
      };
  })
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    $scope.text = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...';
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input ng-model="title" aria-label="title"> <br/>
  <textarea ng-model="text" aria-label="text"></textarea> <br/>
  <pane title="{{title}}"><span>{{text}}</span></pane>
</div>
```

You can also use Multi-slot transclusion, details of which are contained in the link also [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude#multi-slot-transclusion)

Comment: Ric, Thanks for your answer. So the HTML inside <pane> will remain as it is? Also, could you please update the link, it seems broken.

Comment: Updated the link so it should be ok now. The basics of it is, `pane` will render the template, and the contents of `ng-transclude` will be replaced with the dom nodes. you can also have multiple transcludes, which I think is what your'e after

Comment: I guess that's what I need. Will give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can effectively do this: `<group><group-title>{{something}}</group-title><group-body>{{something else}}</group-body></group>`